# Alamofire inputDataNillOrZeroLength Error

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire, registration

whenever I go to press register after filling in all of the fields I get this error popping up. I'm fairly new to swift and XCode and looking up an issue for this problem wasn't very successful.

*URL_USER_REGISTER is a variable that holds the link to my php script. *

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "email":userEmailTextField.text!,
            "password":userPasswordTextField.text!,
            "confirmPassword":confirmPasswordTextField.text!
        ]
        //Sending http post request
        Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: 
parameters).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting the json value from the server
                if let result = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    //displaying the message in label
                    self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: 
"message") as! String?
                }
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually means your `responseJSON` failed because it didn't receive any data back, as explained in the Alamofire documentation.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this?